# How to get the name of the Python file making a call to another file's function?

Tags: python, json

The title is probably confusing, so let me just break my problem down.

For starters, every .py file in my project has a corresponding .json file, eg:
file1.py
file1.json
file2.py
file2.json

I also have a parser.py file, in a python package called modules, with a function inside that simply returns the data from within a json file:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    return json.load(open(filename.replace("py", "json"), 'r'))
```

as of right now, I have it where each .py file, file1.py and file2.py, imports os and sys, and with these imports, obtains the full filename of the current caller, and sends that information to my parser function like so:

```
from modules.parser import parse_file
import os
import sys

running_file = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
json_data = parse_file(running_file)
```

To be clear, what I'm doing is sending each file's name to the parser.parse_file() function in order to translate the name of the file from file1.py to file1.json and return the corresponding data back to file1.py.

My question is, instead of each .py file calling the same imports and copying the same code from the second code snippet above, is there a way I can either move this code to its own .py file, or move it to my parser.py file either as its own method or inside of the parse_file function, and still be able to get the name of the file that called it?

Sorry if this is confusing, I can try to break it down further if necessary. Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's to recommend a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your json files are in the same directory as py files you can try this:

```
from modules.parser import parse_file
json_data = parse_file(__file__)
```

leave `__file__` as is

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better way than how I was going about it!

Comment: Oh, but one question: is there a way to get rid of the path and just print the file name itself? __file__ seems to include the entire path to the file.

Comment: I cant think of an easy or clear way to do so and only thing that comes to mind is some string formating when you do sth like `__file__.split('/')[-1]` so that should split the string by '/' (or maybe they have to be backwards) and it will return a list and last item should be file name.